# How to install an export format in Zotero

Tags: format, export

I am using Zotero as a plugin in Firefox on a Ubuntu12.4 machine.

Since last week, the BibTex format for export seems to have disappeared from the options in the preferences. I have absolutely no idea why and I don't really care why. I simply want to get it back since it worked before.
So I am looking for explanation on how to reinstall this option and eventually on where to get the format.
I tried to desactivate and reactivate the zotero plug-in but it did not work.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved my problem by refreshing firefox, i.e. restoring it to its initial state, then adding the required add-ons and now it works fine again.
I suspect that the upgrade to version 39.0 may be the source of my trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the translators in Preference --> Advanced Tab --> Files and Folders Tab.